# $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\int_{y}^1\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^3}dx=-1/2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis, measure-theory

We want to find an equivalent to $\int_{y}^1\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^3}dx$ when $y \to0.$ It seems that $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\int_{y}^1\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^3}dx=-1/2.$

After Trying an integration by parts, change of variables, dominated convergence theorem.... Didn't find anything.

Is there a way to solve it, maybe a change of variables which I missed, dominated convergence theorem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerator goes to $\infty$ and denominator to $-\infty$

L'Hopital rule
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\int_y^1 \frac{1-\cos x}{x^3} \, dx}{\ln y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\frac{\cos y}{y^3}-\frac{1}{y^3}}{\frac{1}{y}}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\cos y-1}{y^2}=-\frac12$$

Comment: +1 You can bring it even into the standard form of the l'Hopital rule for "$\frac{0}{0}$" writing $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{
\frac{1}{\ln y}}{\frac{1}{\int_y^1 \frac{1-\cos x}{x^3} \, dx}}$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+O\left(x^{4}\right)$, so

\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\int_y^{1}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^3}dx&=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\int_y^{1}\frac{x^2/2}{x^3}dx+O\left(\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\int_{y}^{1}xdx\right)\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\int_y^{1}\frac{x^2/2}{x^3}dx\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{2\ln(y)}\int_y^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{2\ln(y)}(1-\ln(y))\\
&=\frac{-1}{2}
\end{align*}

And so we have

$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\int_y^{1}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^3}dx=-\frac{1}{2}$$.

Not $-1$.